# Blazor __EFMigrationsHistory schema name

Tags: entity-framework-core

I use the following in my `program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<EmployeeManagerDbContext>(
    opt => opt.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("EmployeeManagerDb")));
```

I want to control the schema used by the migrations

I added `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("xxx");` to `OnModelCreating` but that does not affect the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table.

Reading this
https://copyprogramming.com/howto/entity-framework-core-change-schema-of-efmigrationshistory-table
solution #2 does not work as properties are readonly.

For solution #1, I don't know how to access the connection string from configuration.

How have others achieved controlling the schema for `__EFMigrationsHistory`?